# Simply typescript conditional expressions into ternary statements

Tags: typescript, conditional-operator

I have the following `if` statement. Is this expression able to be simplified into a ternary statement? I'm having trouble figuring it out since `group` needs to be assigned based on the value of `coverageLineId`

```
let group;
if(coverageLineId == 1)
  group = this.medicalBenefitsGroupsView.find((x) => x.value === groupValue);
else if (coverageLineId == 2)
  group = this.dentalBenefitsGroupsView.find((x) => x.value === groupValue);
else if (coverageLineId == 3)
  group = this.visionBenefitsGroupsView.find((x) => x.value === groupValue);
```

Comment: Why do you want to make ternary statement ?

Comment: Why not? I usually prefer them to `if` and was having trouble with this one.

Comment: What kind of purpose it will solve ?, will it make code more readable ? Concise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to make it more concise, you can do this:

```js
let group = this[["", "medical", "dental", "vision"][coverageLineId] + "BenefitsGroupsView"].find((x) => x.value === groupValue);
```

However, I think I'd do this:

```js
let view;
switch (coverageLineId) {
    case 1:
        view = this.medicalBenefitsGroupsView; break;
    case 2:
        view = this.dentalBenefitsGroupsView; break;
    case 3:
        view = this.visionBenefitsGroupsView; break;
}
let group = view.find((x) => x.value === groupValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
let group;

group = coverageLineId == 1 ? this.medicalBenefitsGroupsView.find((x) => x.value === groupValue) :
        coverageLineId == 2 ? this.dentalBenefitsGroupsView.find((x) => x.value === groupValue) :
        coverageLineId == 3 ? this.visionBenefitsGroupsView.find((x) => x.value === groupValue) : undefined;
```